# Do type aliases in functions enhance python performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

```
def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]
```

I wonder if this hint is just for better readability or it really does some optimizations.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases

Comment: I think you'll find that the "_type alias_" is the `Vector = List[float]`

Comment: Type hint aliases have nothing to do with performance.

Comment: It's mostly for providing type hints to IDEs. It helps with autocompletion and similar

Comment: @James: that’s an oversimplification and applies to all type hinting, not just to aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, an alias does not convey any kind of performance optimisation.

It just makes it easier to read your code. It is easier to reason about a function accepting a `Vector` and returning (another) `Vector`, than it is to use the more generic `List[float]` type in the signature of `scale()`.

Use aliases the same way you would use constants in your code. For example, if your code needed to calculate acceleration in free-fall, you'd store `9.807` as the `EARTH_GRAVITY` constant, rather than just use `9.807` in your code. Using `EARTH_GRAVITY` makes your code easier to read.